# Generated swf does not work on server

Tags: haxe, openfl

When I compile my project to flash target, every thing is fine, if I double click the resulted swf file, it will open with local flash player properly.

But, when I try to host the swf file on xampp, and load it via html file at `http://127.0.0.1/testopenflswf/index.html` , I get only blank screen..

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#eeeeee">

    <object
      classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
      codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=11,0,0,0"
      width="1200"
      height="800"
      id="myFlashObject"
    >
      <param name="movie" value="DCACLabjsclientside.swf"/>
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="salign" value="lt" />
      <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
      <param name="menu" value="false" />
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#00ffff"/>
      <embed
        src="DCACLabjsclientside.swf"
        quality="high"
        salign="lt"
        width="1200"
        height="800"
        align="middle"
        scale="noscale"
        menu="false"
        bgcolor="#00ffff"
        name="myFlashObject"
        swLiveConnect="true"
        allowScriptAccess="always"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
      />
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

if I try to test it on ubuntu, I get this error inside the swf area:

```
Assets.hx: 792: [openfl.Assets] There is no asset library named "Compo"
```

But, Compo library loads fine without the server, and its defined in project as:

```
<haxelib name="swf" version="1.1.1" />
<library path="Assets/compact-dcaclabs-assets-cc.swf" name="Compo"/>
```

Any one can help?

Comment: what happens when you open the html file in the browser without the server?

Comment: I get the same result, just blank area

Comment: if you're opening the swf with the debug player when testing it in standalone that could be the problem, the debug player is less* restrict and, for example, allows you to open tcp connections without checking for cross domain policies, in non-debug if you opened a non-autorhized connection it will block the code and display an error only after a while [edit: i wrote more instead of less]

Comment: I found that there were an error, at chrome it was a silent error, at IE, I saw the error alert with exact line! poor developers, many hours goes to discover silly things..